# A clear visualization of a two-way ANOVA

Tags: r, statistics, visualization

To provide a full yet simple picture of a 3-level, one-way ANOVA, I use the following visualization where ***variation within each group*** (the filled circles) and ***variation between the groups*** (black arrows) are simple to be understood.

But I'm wondering if it could be possible to extend the current visualization to a **2 x 3 two-way ANOVA** (adding another way with two groups to the current visualization)?

(**Note:** the dashed vertical lines denote each group's mean)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a 3D plot, but they are only useful in specific situations (e.g. simple bar plot, a surface etc.), and definitely not here. Your best option, while keeping the overall design of your plot, seems to be to split your data by the factor with 2 levels, and plot each separately in 2 panels side by side. That way, you can compare similarities, baseline shifts, and interactions.